# How to search from datagridview using textbox then bind the rows' data to labels? C# / SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to search from datagridview and bind the result to these labels:

[image]

I am working on C# and SQL Server CE, my project is almost done just need these few things done.

Basically I want to search in datagridview using ID of customers, and when search is matched, I want the data from the matching row to be bound to the labels (or text boxes).

I want to search the gridview through a textbox not from datagridview directly.

Comment: Fun fact: real life CSRs dont memorize all the Ids of all the Products, Clients, Shippers etc.

Comment: @Plutonix I know but this is for practice only

Comment: use loop then if matched you have now the index of what row is it. then transfer it to the label that will hold the specific data

Comment: @Muj how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for each row as datagridview in dgName.rows
 if txtSearch.text = row.cells("cell name you want to compare").value 'you can add OR here if you want to compare it in multiple cells
  lb1.text = row.cells("cell name that assigned in label1").value
  . . .and so on
 end if
next
```

Just inform me if this is not functioning well